# Laravel-websoket - broadcasts nothing if the backend is on another port

Tags: laravel

My laravel works like restapi. Front and back on different ports, nginx proxies requests to the back or front.

I can connect from the browser to the web socket on port 6001 without any problems, as can be seen in the statistics, there are no errors in the console. The statistics itself is also available on port 6001, i.e. the web socket is working fine.

But Laravel broadcasts no events on the working server, in statistics and console it is empty.
Nothing blocks traffic, the firewall is disabled.

I spent half a day, but still did not understand what the problem was.

Any thoughts ...

Answer (score 1):

Friends, as always, the answer was simple. In the production process, I did not fix the .env log on the pusher (((